# How can I loop through a graph's vertices instead of having a separate add.vertex for each vertex?

Tags: java, loops, graph

So here is what I have below

```
void vader(int name)
    {
        vertices[size++] = new Vertex(name);
    }

Graph graph = new Graph(7);

    graph.vert(1);
    graph.vert(2);
    graph.vert(3);
    graph.vert(4);
    graph.vert(5);
    graph.vert(6);
    graph.vert(7);
```

Instead of having these 7 lines of code to add 7 vertices is there any way I can have a loop that adds 7 vertices?

Answer (score 1):

use a for loop like this

```
Graph graph = new Graph(7);
for(int i=1;i<=7;i++){


    graph.vert(i);

}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch this was it.